# Jupyter reload custom mplstyles

Tags: python, matplotlib, styles

I want to develop custom styles for plots in matplotlib. For this reason I have a custom stylesheet (`my_style.mpstyle`) located in the default directory (`~/.config/matplotlib/styles`). I can do this with Python scripts without a problem but recently I find myself using Jupyter more. Although the stylesheets generally work, I have the problem, that changes in the stylesheet are not considered unless I restart the Kernel - is there a way of reloading the stylesheet when I execute the cell such that I can develop the style with Jupyter?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got around this problem by defining a [PYTHONSTARTUP file](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONSTARTUP).  This is a file that contains a set of python commands (usually `import` statements) that are automatically executed every time you launch a python interpreter, even when launching a jupyter application or restarting a kernel within one.

Here's a portion of my startup file that imports pyplot and sets a style sheet.

```
try:
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    print('import matplotlib.pyplot as plt') 
except:
    print('Could not import matplotlib.pyplot')
try:
    plt.style.use('mystylesheet')
except:
    print('No mpl style sheet set; could not find "mystylesheet"')
```

To make python execute the startup file, you need to define the environmental variable `PYTHONSTARTUP=full/path/to/startupfile`.  In Linux, it's quite easy; just modify your `.bashrc` to include

```
export PYTHONSTARTUP="full/path/to/startupfile"
```

For windows it is a little more involved, and of course the process varies from one version to another.  [Here is one website](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml) that appears to summarize the process for several versions.